# Getting last element of the Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

guys, I'm trying to get the last element from the data returned to me but the problem is that it is throwing me an error which is

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::last()
```

Here is my code

```
$last_saved_snapshot = \EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::where('engine_performance_test_id', $id)->last();
```

Please tell me what is it that I'm doing wrong. Thanks

P.S I'm using Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found another way to do it and that is:

```
$last_saved_snapshot = \EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::where('engine_performance_test_id', $id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

This is working but if somebody can tell me why is the last not working then that would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: The `last()` method is an Eloquent method, while in you question you are still building a query. So the solution is to either execute the query with `get()` so that you have a collection where you can take the last item from using `last()`, or reversing the order like you have done in this answer. The later is more performant since it keeps the data in the database layer.

Answer (score 23):

Try something like that:

```
$last_saved_snapshot = \EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::where('engine_performance_test_id', $id)
    ->get()
    ->last();
```

Comment: the same one call to undefined method

Comment: with this same class (`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`)?

Comment: yes with the same class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Comment: So you do something wrong, on my computer `->get()` don't return `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` but `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. You need run `->get()` before `->last()`. Can you paste output of this commands?

        `echo get_class(\EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::where('engine_performance_test_id', $id));`
        `echo get_class(\EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::get());`

Comment: and that is how I'm doing it running ->get before ->last and sure I'll get you the output. Right now I'm outside as soon as I get home I'll paste the output

Answer (score 10):

The last method call is not working because `namespace Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;` does not have any `last()` method. The right way to do this is to do something like this:

```
$last_saved_snapshot = EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::query()
    ->where('engine_performance_test_id', $id)
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->first();
```

Otherwise, you need to get all items, since `last()` is part of the collection class so it expects a collection or array to be able to work and not a query builder. It is less efficient and a bad practice to fetch all data just for one.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, less code:

```
\EnginePerformanceTestSnapshot::
    where('engine_performance_test_id', $id)
    ->latest()
    ->first();
```